# Jersey Test Framework - define default error response for all unknown paths in grizzly

Tags: java, testing, facebook-graph-api, jersey, grizzly

To test our API that connects to the facebook graph API we use a mock server setup based on Jersey Test Framework and grizzly:

```
@Path("/" + PostRest.RESOURCE)
@Produces("application/json")
public class PostRest {

    public static final String RESOURCE = "111_222";

    @GET
    public Response getPost(@QueryParam("access_token") String access_token) {
        if (access_token != VALID_TOKEN) {
            return Response.status(400).entity(createErrorJson()).build();
        }
        return Response.status(200).entity(createSomeJsonString()).build();
    }
```

Now while I can react to an invalid or missing access_token with the correct error response, I also want to test that my API reacts correctly when trying to access an **unkown resource at facebook** ie an unkown path.

Right now I get a 404 from my grizzly obviously, if I try to access say "/111_2", but facebook seems to catch that error and wrap it inside a **Json response**, containing the string **"false"** with **status 200**.

So... How do I set up the Test Framework to return

```
Response.status(200).entity("false").build();
```

every time it is called for an known path?

Basic example:

```
@ContextConfiguration({ "classpath:context-test.xml" })
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
public class SomeTest extends JerseyTest {

    @Inject
    private SomeConnection connection;

    private String unkownId = "something";


    public SomeTest() throws Exception {
        super("jsonp", "", "com.packagename.something");
    }


    @Test(expected = NotFoundException.class)
    public void testUnkownObjectResponse() throws NotFoundException {
        // here it should NOT result in a 404 but a JSON wrapped error response 
        // which will be handled by the Connection class and 
        // result in a custom exception 
        connection.getObject(unkownId);
    }
```

**Or maybe I can set up grizzly to behave as desired..?!**

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Obviously facebook has it own service to intercept errors. Same thing should be done in your code. Just expose you own **test** service that intercepts all request

```
@Path("/test/errorTrap")
public class ErrorTrapService{
 ....
}
```

This service will produce any response you want. So any un-existing pages like http://mytest/test/errorTrap/111_2 will be intercepted by test service and produce expected response for you

Comment: So your solution suggests that I create just another resource that will produce the desired response and access it in one of my tests? Which pretty much means, creating a known resource and calling it unknown? That's what I planned on doing at first.. 
But your thought about exposing gave me an idea. I might try to intercept the grizzly filter chain, check if the call can be forwared to an existing resource and if not forward it to a default location which then will produce the desired error...
I'll update this post with the final result for anyone interested.
Thanks for now!

Comment: @Pete "will produce the desired response and access it in one of my tests? " - yes, you get it! You are welcome.